# Ant LibusbJava compile error: "jni.h: No such file"...fixed, now a memset error

Tags: linux, ant, java-native-interface, libusb, memset

There appears to be a [Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant) / jni.h problem (for my setup) with LibusbJava. I get the following error when setting up LibusbJava by running

```
ant linux
```

in [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 6.3 as root (quick and dirty test, thanks for those concerned about user level =0). I will redo with proper restrictions as shown on a libusbjava reference after reflection when first install works. LibusbJava, is a Java wrapper for the [libusb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libusb) library.

The output starts out like this:

```
[root@somebox LibusbJava]# ant linux -lib $JAVA_HOME/include -lib $JAVA_HOME/include/linux
Buildfile: build.xml

clean:

Build LibusbJava Test Linux:

Build LibusbJava Test:
     [echo] Building Library for unit tests:
     [exec] /.../libusbjava/trunk/LibusbJava/LibusbJava.cpp:27:17: error: jni.h: No such file or directory
     [exec] /.../libusbjava/trunk/LibusbJava/LibusbJava.cpp:34:26: error: test/CuTest.h: No such file or directory
 `...`
```

as it was not set on my system. It appears that jni.h is a header called by [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) code, which I had to add to the LibusbJava.cpp file. This is the new include, `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64/include/jni.h`. I then get an error with jni.h not being able to fine jni_md.h which is an include in jni.h `#include "jni_md.h"`.

Clearly this is not the right approach, so perhaps I need a correct Ant reference, but I cannot seem to do it with a `-lib` switch. Besides, this just creates thousands of `jni.h` file errors during the Ant build attempt.

How can I fix this problem?

Notes: I've set`$JAVA_HOME` up like `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.9.x86_64` and `javac` and `java` work fine.

---

New discovery... after helpful questions which guided me, I am much closer to successful compilation.

When I install LibusbJava and manually install all the library references in build.xml there is still an error compiling the LibusbJava based on a memset error. I see memset patches for libusb that appeared in 2007 and it's unclear how to use or if they relate. Investigating... Hints, comments and questions welcome. My most sincere thanks for the help thus far.

```
 [exec] /.../libu/libusbjava/trunk/LibusbJava/objects/Usb_Device.cpp: In function ‘void Usb_Device_disconnect(JNIEnv*)’:
 [exec] /.../libu/libusbjava/trunk/LibusbJava/objects/Usb_Device.cpp:88: error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope
[antcall] Exiting /.../libu/libusbjava/trunk/LibusbJava/build.xml.

BUILD FAILED
```

but I find no referece to an include string.h or cstring. The header of Usb_Device.cpp mentions it is a `C++ Stub for the java class of a java class ch.ntb.inf.libusbJava.Usb_Device.` which only has this include `#include "Usb_Device.h" which also does not appear to have a string include. Perhaps just insertion of`#include`?

Comment: Can you look through the ant file to see what actually gets passed to the `-I` flag to `cc`?

Comment: Good info: Looks like it was not getting the /include/linux directory... build.xml appears to be the place to insert this, it seems to make it past that point. Thanks!

Comment: Well, ideally, `build.xml` should be flexible enough to not require monkeypatching, but if you don't need this to be reproducible whatever gets the job is fine.

Comment: millimoose, thank you for the comment about reproducable. ultimately yes it's needed, but I'm at the wanting to see the code compile first. Good thinking... will continue to research ant.

Comment: You probably just don't have the necessary reputation. Either way doesn't matter, it's not like comment upgrades give reputation. They're more a tool for you as the asker to know which of the comments are actually useful.